# Ground loop noise goes away when heater comes on

Tags: audio, isolation

I have a ground loop or something in a stereo wiring. I have 3 stereo's connected all with the same inputs(fanout).

One stereo several feet away from the other two has an annoying amount of hum. (sounds like outside crickets)

What is very odd is that when a small heater comes on the noise on the stereo completely goes away(along with the lights dimming slightly). I'm sure there is some noise but the high frequency buzz goes away.

How could a heater, which I think is even on an alternate circuit, cause the stereo to *stop* humming? One would think it would be the opposite problem?

I guess the voltage lag might have something to do with it.

As a extra issue, anyone know of a quick way to kill ground loops easily? I don't want to have to buy some isolation boxes as they have gotten extremely expensive(100$+ for stereo). I think I do have some audio transformers that I might roll my own but it would be nice to find the issue. The one stereo isn't ground but all 3 are connected star(plugged into the same outlet). I'm thinking though I might have a bad wire somewhere.

Comment: Your stereo gear is all on the same outlet? I would think the heater current is raising the voltage of your neutral wire. But not if they are all the same. One way to kill loops is to disconnect shielding at one end of a cable. Preferably keep it connected at the source end. This way there is no current in the shield. Proper instrumentation shielding works this way.

Answer (score 2):

Quick way to *improve* ground loops is to connect a decent thick earth cable between all the audio devices.

If you have a typical 1 mA leakage current, carried by a long cheap audio cable ground, easily a few Ohms, it will generate a few mV, which gets added to the signal, and will be audible.

With a fat ground wire, the voltage drop between the two chassis will be a hundred times smaller.

It should be quick to try with a piece of household mains wire.

This brute force method is recommended (by me) even if you do the other things, adding transformers, etc.

Answer (score 0):

If your devices all use the same circuit then they are all connected by a heavy ground wire in a star configuration. That is, if they all use mains power and a grounded power cord (3 prong in the U.S.). The loop would be from shielding, or ground wires in signal cables and the power cords. Any current in those "grounds" by definition means they are not at ground potential compared to the point that ties all the ground wires together. The power cord ground is for safety, so disconnect ground wires/shields and see what happens.

Also, how old is the equipment? Does it use heavy transformers and linear regulators? The iron leaves in transformers can become loose with age and vibrate just slightly with the 60 Hz. This translates to the magnetics and transmits some RF. It is remotely possible (I have seen this more than once) that the change in input voltage when the heater comes on is low enough to stop a mechanical effect.

Disconnect all the cables and use a voltmeter from the shields or chassis on one device to each of the others. Try for all combinations and see if one is leaking excess current to ground.

If the heater has a fan, can you turn it on without the heater load? What happens if you substitute a couple hundred watts of light bulb on the circuit the heater uses?

Some ideas anyway. Can't give a definitive answer as this is not the usual kind of question here.

Comment: Seems that a brand new walmart stereo cable was bad. The ground wire was broke, hence the ground loop. What the hell is this world coming too when you pay more for crapper stuff?